# What is with NHibernate.DomainModel

Tags: nhibernate

Sorry if this question belongs somewhere else.

I am going through the source for NHibernate and there is a project called NHibernate.DomainModel with a bunch of seemingly useless classes.

What are those for?  They don't appear to be used by NHibernate except for the other classes in that project and in the unit tests written for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are used for unit testing. You need a domain to test NHibernate features on.